# What is Ideal tool to manage PHP code with a team?

Tags: php, git, share

I am looking for a solution for code management in the company.
We have a lot of projects that we work on on a daily basis. And sometimes two developers are required to work on the same project simultaneously.
An optimal situation for us is that each developer will have his local environment. And when he updates his code, the changes will be updated by all developers automatically.
And so virtually all developers will have the constantly updated version.

The problem with GIT is that the upload/download has to be manual, so the developer may forget to download a version.

We work in a PC environment.

Please, inspire me :)

Comment: Sorry dude, this is going to get closed fast for being opinion based... But, sharing my opinion, I don't think it's such a great idea. Automatically updated sandboxes would mean your developers are constantly getting their files changed under their feet. What would you want to have happen when there's a conflict, or even just a non-conflicting change to a file that's open in your editor? Merging is not always trivial, and warrants review, which is why I think it needs to stay manual, or at least manually triggered.

Answer (score 3):

My employer had this same problem, and came to the conclusion that there is only one way to handle it:

**Teach your developers to use git properly.** Ideally, teach them some kind of system for branching and merging, such as [git-flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) or [GitLab Flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html).

Some git tools can help you by automatically querying the server every 10 minutes to see if someone else has pushed new commits and prompt you to download them. (I think VSCode has this feature, but I don't remember for sure. Personally, I use SmartGit which also has this feature.)